# Windows 10, Sound rise to 90 when plugging audio device

Tags: windows, usb, audio, sound-card

Each time I plug an audio device with a sound card, windows automatically switch to this card (ok, why not) but also rise the volume level to 90 which lead to hurt my ears and my speakers (it does this for all audio devices who are plugged with usb not for thoses who are linked by bluetooth).

I'll be happy if it set volume to a generic louder level but not 90.
I've tried the common windows set of advises to change this (repair, update, uninstall drivers, disable all audios enhancements etc...).
I thought there's a config option somewhere to set that but i can't find it.

Thanks for all advises / tips.

Comment: If you set the device volume to 50%, remove the device, then re-attach it, does the volume go to 50%, or back to 90%? Any volume you set should persist when the device is re-attached.

Comment: The volume back to 90%, but you made me think, these devices are always plugged via an usb hub, i'm looking around that.

Comment: Also related https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/opting-out-of-volume-level-persistence